# О фразеологизме "умываю руки": в каком разговоре его уместно использовать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, семантика

Значение фразеологизма понятное, о его происхождении тоже можно найти **[информацию](https://dzen.ru/a/WkXR-4MJBdB3R3vN).** Но **в какой ситуации** его следует использовать?

Прежде всего, речевой оборот представляется **недостаточно вежливым** в разговоре **малознакомых** людей. Также студент профессору на экзаменах вряд ли такое скажет.

К примеру, эта фраза возможна **в разговоре с друзьями**, да и то **не всегда.**

Вот вы пришли **к другу за консультацией**, но единого мнения не получилось. Друг объясняет, вы возражаете, а в результате говорите ему: **"Всё! Я умываю руки!"**  И уходите.

А друг в недоумении после вашего ухода: "Это же он ко мне пришел, а не я к нему. Да и то как-то грубо звучит, я бы так не сказал."

Как вы думаете, **кто из собеседников прав?** Можно ли найти информацию **об этичности** и особой **стилистической** оценке этой фразы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не, ну руки не связаны с консультацией. Руками не говорят(ну разве глухонемые), а делают, воздействуют или манипулируют. Вообще вот слово man английское, как Дугин говорит, и мне кажется это логичным и верным, от слова manus - рука. Тоже сюда правая рука(десница) - то есть главный помощник или соратник у князя. Рука господа, руководство и тп. Есть такая поговорка или мудрость, что мужчина должен руки содержать в чистоте и порядке - ну ногти стричь, мыть, - если сантехник какой или землю копал, чтобы не с грязными ходить. То есть умывать руки можно по окончанию какого-то дела. Ну и раз руки прямо нужно мыть, то дело наверное грязное. То есть когда дело оказывается сомнительным и в нем не хочется больше участвовать, то говорят - умываю руки, то есть выхожу из дела, из игры и тп., потому что я бессилен что-то сделать, хотел помочь, руки не опускал, но не получается, потому всё - умываю руки, - или потому что дело не внушает доверия, мутное, грязное, нечестное.

Ну по ссылке текст вполне логичный и внятный, все так, может и из Библии идиома. Кстати в английском тоже вроде есть "I wash my hands of". То есть идиома интернациональная, значит, скорее всего библейская.

Насчёт сценки, ну ситуация комичная, но может быть пришедший за помощью имел ввиду, что "умываю руки" относится не к другу вообще, а к тому делу, о которое он пытался решить привлекая друга. Но другу стоило всё же сказать слова благодарности за попытку помочь. Но ввиду опять же недостаточности контекста, сложно сказать, что конкретно произошло.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне очень интересна стилистическая оценка фразы. Я здесь чувствую негативную экспрессию, поэтому ее не употребляю.  Другие же носители языка, возможно,   говорят только про то, что не хотят  продолжать спор, и для них это вполне приличная фраза.  Такое взаимное непонимание может отрицательно сказаться на отношениях между людьми.

Comment: И еще. В Нацкорпусе примеров  по теме много, и можно заметить, что раньше  действительно больше говорили о неблаговидных делах, употребляя эту фразу. А сейчас могут сказать про любые дела, а также  про нежелание продолжать спор. К примеру, кто-то не умеет выбирать подарки, и ему хотят помочь. Человек  с радостью соглашается и говорит: «Вот и прекрасно! Тогда я умываю руки!». Это правильно?

Comment: @Sharon Наверное да, в начальном смысле с негативными нотками, чего зря руки мыть, если дело чистое). А с руками, ну нет, тогда нужно говорить я отдаю себя в ваши руки, вам на поруки, или я вам доверяю, доверюсь. То есть тут перепутаны идиомы с руками), не помню как это терминологически называется, когда путают слова схожие по звучанию, но разные по семантике, что-то в этом роде. Ну не когда омонимы, а когда адреса и адресант) паронимы! короче это какая-то паронимия, но фразеологического толка)

Comment: "Фразеологическими паронимами называются близкие по звучанию, но различные по значению устойчивые словосочетания типа язык проглотил «молчит» и язык проглотишь «вкусный», руками и ногами «охотно» и с руками и ногами «целиком»."

Comment: А как вы  к "умываю руки" относитесь, сами используете в речи? Есть в нем  негативная экспрессия для вас? Обидитесь, если собеседник вам так скажет или это нормально?

Comment: @Sharon не знаю, вроде не использую), может как раз из-за негативного подтекста. Надо будет попробовать использовать) - или руки умыть, или морду начистить.

Comment: Смешно! Мы неповторимы, когда смеемся)

Comment: @Sharon кстати использовал, правда англичанину на английском написал, вошу май хедз оф в споре, что мол надоело спорить-доказывать, оставайтесь в своём неведении дальше)